# Not able to see object values inside an object from Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm posting data from somewhere to Google Apps Script.

I'm getting this JSON string with code below:

> {"postData":{"contents":"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]","length":159,"name":"postData","type":"application/json"},"queryString":"","parameters":{},"contextPath":"","contentLength":159,"parameter":{}}

```
function doPost(e){
    var JSONString = JSON.stringify(e);

    var JSONOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSONString);
    JSONOutput.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    return JSONOutput
}
```

How do I access the `contents` objects one by one? I want to add the data to a sheet later on but I tried double `JSON.stringify` and didn't have any success.

Comment: I think whatever called your script uploaded the data incorrectly

Comment: the data was uploading correctly and i was able to solve it. strangely it does not give you the object out when logging or printing but it does give the fields of object with regular javascript style accessing array

Comment: Read about Stackdriver Logging. Regular `Logger` is very limited